# scope of php variable

Tags: php, function, scope

I have come across a problem while dealing with php variables.

There are following 2 arrays --

```
$fruits = array();
$persons = array();
```

and they are being used in following foreach loop --

```
foreach ($fruits as $name => $prop) {
     foreach ($persons as $person) {
          assignToPerson($name);
     }
}

function assignToPerson($name) {
     ..data processing..
}
```

So suppose, for the first iteration of $fruits, $persons iterate for 5 times and `assignToPerson()` is called every time from inside the 2nd foreach loop. Everything goes well for 1st iteration of `$persons`, but on the 2nd iteration `$name` is destroyed and a blank value is passed. Even though I have not used `$name` variable in the function `assignToPerson()`.

I found a way around --

```
foreach ($fruits as $name => $prop) {
     $tmp = $name;
     foreach ($persons as $person) {
          assignToPerson($tmp);
     }
}
```

Now while using a temporary variable the same issue is resolved. But I'm totally unaware of the reason behind the above situation. please guide me.

Comment: accessing $name in a second foreach should be fine, there are no language limits here. scope of $name is valid with foreach

Comment: it has to be worked. No problem in your first code snippets.

Comment: Can you echo $name in the loops the whole time?

Comment: @nerdlyist - its value gets printed for only first time, if echo inside 2nd foreach loop.

Comment: Can you show us actual values?

Comment: @Pankaj then I would suggest the above comment and let us see some data and even perhaps what is going on in assignToPerson($name)